# Return referenced sheet name within an formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to check which spreadsheet is being referenced **within** a formula.

For example, I have the following reference `=('2015'!A1)` and I need to check which sheet I am using in the reference. In this example it's "**2015**". But sometimes I changes to "2016", sometimes to "2012"... Is there a way to check or return the referenced sheet within the formula? Preferably without VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that specific format with brackets and your formulas are simple as your example, this will do the trick:

```
=MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND("(",FORMULATEXT(A1))+1,FIND("!",FORMULATEXT(A1))-FIND("(",FORMULATEXT(A1))-1)
```

Comment: Note that `formulatext` was introduced in Excel 2013 (_I think_)  Can't think of any non-vba equivalent prior to that.

Comment: Nope, there is none prior to 2013 as far as I know as well.

Comment: Generally speaking, not even this works on even a bit more complex formula, or the one without brackets :)

Comment: 'formulatext' did the job... this was the thing I needed actually but didn't know it existed :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll add this as an answer for versions earlier than Excel 2013.

You can use an Excel 4 Macro Function in a named range to return the formula in a cell.

This formula *as a named range* will return the formula in the cell above the formula:

```
=GET.CELL(6,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),-1,0))
```

I'll add this link for more info on the other types of info that can be returned:  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20611-info-only-get-cell-arguments.html

Comment: One needs to save the file as xlsm i.e. Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook whenever using XLM 4 Macro functions. May not be important but worth noting.

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij  Good point - I read that somewhere and forgot to add it (and when you try and save it complains:  _The following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks :  Excel 4.0 function stored in defined names_)